# Using Camera API in android to take picture in different focus modes

Tags: android, camera

I need to create an app where when I click a photo it will save 3 jpegs is different focus modes(auto focus, Macro focus and Infinite focus) if possible and save it. I have made a basic camera app whoe code I am posting..Can you guys tell me how to implement this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  Constants,SurfaceHolder.Callback,Camera.PreviewCallback,
Camera.AutoFocusCallback, OnTouchListener{
private ViewFlipper myviewflipper;
private float initialXpoint;
private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceView mPreviewSV;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private Button mCapture;
private Button mChange;
private Button mReturn;
private Button mLoad;
private ImageView mImageView;
private int mPicturesCaptured = 0;

boolean isCaptureClicked = false;
boolean encodingCompleted = false;

long startTime;
int currentFile = 0;
int initialPointer = -1;
int secondPointer = -1;
int direction = -1;

CameraSize picSize = BACK_CAM_PREVIEW_SIZE_3 ;
File mFile;
ArrayList<String> imagePath;
ProgressDialog mEncodingProgress;
DisplayTask mTask;
Bitmap mDisplayBitmap;
File path;
File[] files;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFile = new File(Constants.Cameraeffect);
    if (!mFile.exists())
        mFile.mkdir();
    setupUI();
}

private void setupUI()
{
    mPreviewSV = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sv_cam_preview);
    mCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    mChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    mReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_return);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_load);
    mSurfaceHolder = mPreviewSV.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            deleteFiles();
            mPicturesCaptured = 0;
            isCaptureClicked = true;
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            progressUpdate();
        }
    });
    mChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int res = getCurrentCameraId();
            switch(res){
                case 0:
                    stopCamera();
                    startCamera(Constants.FRONT_CAMERA);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stopCamera();
                    startCamera(Constants.BACK_CAMERA);
                    break;  
            }
        }
    });

    mLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            imagePath=ListAllFiles();
            mImageView.bringToFront();
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(imagePath.get(0)));
            mTask = new DisplayTask();
            mTask.execute("");
        }
    });
    mReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}




private ArrayList<String> ListAllFiles() {
    ArrayList<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    path= new File(Constants.Cameraeffect);
    if( path.exists() ) {
        files = path.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            tFileList.add(files[i].toString());
        }
    }
    return tFileList;
}

 public void deleteFiles() {
        path= new File(Constants.Cameraeffect);
        if( path.exists() ) {
            files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                    files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
int getCurrentCameraId() {
    int mCameraId = -1;
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
            return Constants.BACK_CAMERA;
        }
        else if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            return Constants.FRONT_CAMERA;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}

private void progressUpdate()
{
    mEncodingProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mEncodingProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mEncodingProgress.setMessage("Encoding");
    mEncodingProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
    mEncodingProgress.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<=5000)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    mEncodingProgress.setProgress(mPicturesCaptured + 1);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void startCamera(int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
            stopCamera();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(1280,720);
        parameters.setFocusMode("infinite");
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
        parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
        parameters.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
        parameters.setRotation(0);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreviewSV.getHolder());
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        stopCamera();
    }
}

private void stopCamera()
{
    if (mCamera != null)
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreviewSV.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    stopCamera();
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    stopCamera();
    super.onDestroy();
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{

}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    startCamera(0);
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{

}

public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    if (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime<=5000)
    {
        savingJpegToSDCard(data);
    }
    else 
    {
        if(mEncodingProgress!=null){
            mEncodingProgress.dismiss();
            mEncodingProgress=null;
            encodingCompleted=true;
        }
    }
    if(encodingCompleted){
        /*
         *   Log.i("","sent to JNI");
         */

        encodingCompleted=false;
    }
}

public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("","srikrishna:: ontouch");
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        initialPointer=(int) event.getX();
        break;
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        secondPointer=(int) event.getX();
        break;
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        initialPointer=(int) event.getX();
    }
    return true;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String fPath)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    opts.inDither = false;
    opts.inPurgeable = true;
    opts.inInputShareable = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fPath, opts);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 500;
    int scale = 1;
    if (opts.outHeight > REQUIRED_SIZE || opts.outWidth > REQUIRED_SIZE)
    {
        final int heightRatio = Math
                .round((float) opts.outHeight / (float) REQUIRED_SIZE);
        final int widthRatio = Math
                .round((float) opts.outWidth / (float) REQUIRED_SIZE);
        scale = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;//
    }

    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opts.inSampleSize = scale;

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fPath, opts).copy(
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);
    return bm;
}

private void savingJpegToSDCard(final byte[] b1)
{
    try{ 
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); 
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize(); 
        Log.i("","abh size width and height "+size.width + " "+size.height);
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(b1, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),size.width, size.height, null); 
        File file = new File(Constants.Cameraeffect + "/File" + mPicturesCaptured + ".jpeg");
        FileOutputStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,filecon); 
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    mPicturesCaptured++;
}

class DisplayTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        currentFile = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        while(true){
            Log.i("","abh imagePath.size() "+imagePath.size());
            if(secondPointer-initialPointer >50)
            {
                Log.i("","abh currentFile "+currentFile);
                mDisplayBitmap = decodeFile(imagePath.get(currentFile));
                publishProgress(mDisplayBitmap);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(currentFile<=90)
                    currentFile++;
                initialPointer=secondPointer;               
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your start camera method set the focus mode to the required one  and start the camera. If you want to change it dynamically on click of  button then you must call the start camera method with the required attributes. Make sure you are releasing camera[this is very imp] also note that the custom camera implementation in android is very buggy[many of the bugs are stil open just goggle it and see] i suggest you read it carefully and implement it.

Comment: I don't want to change the focus on the click of a button, what I want is on clicking the capture button 3 photos will be captured simultaneously in the three different focus modes! 

Is there any focus callback method which will return true if the capture of the image is possible at that particular focus? Of that were possible then I would use that and use switch case to toggle between the different focuses..!